# How do I make buttons in two separate C# forms in two separate projects open each other?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, reference, dependencies

I am working with two C# projects in one Microsoft Visual Studios solution. One project contains a form used to select which form from the other project to open. I also have a 'Back' button on each of my Project 2 forms, which I hope to use to reopen the form selector from the first project. I have researched how to get around circular reference dependencies with no luck. I would prefer to keep these as two separate projects. Will I need to consolidate everything into one messy project, or is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I found a simple, but effective solution. I only need to reference Project 2 from Project 1, because I can pass through the Project 1 form as a parameter into the Project 2 forms, then display the first form whenever a button is clicked. Thank you again.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms (as in, is the `Form` class in the following namespace: `System.Windows.Forms`)? Could you also post some code, please, especially the code you use to open a form from Project 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a New Project (say 'Opener') in the same solution as a simple command utility.
2. Add the reference to the main projects to Opener.
3. In Program.cs add the following code:

   private static void OpenForm(String formName)
   {
       if (formName == "Form1")
           // Open your Form1
       else
           // Open second Form2
   }
4. Now you can just open the forms on the button click event click by:

   Process.Start("Opener.exe Form1");

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seems like an intelligent solution but I do have a question about how to implement it. If I have one 'Opener' project, which is called by Project 1 to open Project 2 and called by Project 2 to open Project 1, then the 'Opener' project will need to reference Project 1 and 2, and Project 1 and 2 will need to reference Opener, resulting in the same problem. Do I need two Opener projects, one called by Project 1 to open Project 2, and the other called by Project 2 to open Project 1? Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need to reference Opener project in any other project. Just call its .exe using the Process.Start. if it helps, just mark the answer as accepted. :)